# Android - How to hide a control in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android

In my preferences UI, I need to hide a preference based on certain conditions.

```
public class MyFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
  public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(...);
    ListPreference myList = (ListPreference) findPreference("myid");

    ...
    if (condition) {
      // hide myList
    }
 }
```

}

I cannot seem to find any method either on ListPreference or on PreferenceFragment to hide it from being shown in the UI. Would appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: ListPreference hide/disable value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954927/android-listpreference-hide-disable-value)

Comment: I had already seen that one. It talks about hiding the values when the list control is displayed. In my case, I wish to remove the control itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After much debugging, turns out it was quite simple. Here is what you need to do:

First, obtain the PreferenceCategory the item belongs to. Next, just call removePreference on it.

```
 PreferenceCategory myCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("myPrefCategory");
 myCategory.removePreference(myList);
```

Comment: What if the `ListPreference` does not belong to a category?

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering how to remove item that has no parent category - you should name your root like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:key="root_preferences">
<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Developer tools"
        android:key="dev_tools_category">
```

Then for example:

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    PreferenceScreen rootPreferences = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("root_preferences");
    PreferenceCategory devCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("dev_tools_category");
    rootPreferences.removePreference(devCategory);
}
```

In example above "dev_tools_category" could be any preference widget or like I showed - a category.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the inherited methods from the `Preference` superclass.

```
myList.setShouldDisableView(true);
myList.setEnabled(false);
```

The first will make the backing view of the preference disappear when the preference is disabled, the second will actually disable the preference.

Comment: This is close. However, the line item in the preference dialog still shows up although now it is grayed out.

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason (maybe it used to work in versions older than Lollipop). Preference is grayed out.